# Why i cant do this query with relations in yii project?

Tags: php, yii

I would like to create a query with Yii relations. This is my relation:

```
//Articles model
return array(
            'articlesHasTags' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ArticlesHasTag', 'articles_id',
                            "with"=>"tag",
                            ),
                            ),
//ArticlesHasTag model
        return array(
            'articles' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Articles', 'articles_id'),
            'tag' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tag', 'tag_id'),
        );
```

This is the query:

```
  $blog = Articles::model()->with(array("articlesHasTags"))->findAllByAttributes(array(),array(
        "condition"=>"t.del = 0 AND t.active = 1 AND articlesHasTags.tag_id = {$tag->id}",
        'order'=>"t.publish_start DESC",
        "limit"=>10,
    ));
```

Before i get the `$tag->id`.

The error message is:

> Unknown column 'articlesHasTags.tag_id'

I think the relation is good because i can use it without this "`articlesHasTags.tag_id = {$tag->id}`"

I change the relation name to table name. Then the full error message is:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'articles_has_tag.tag_id' in
>   'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`id` AS
>   `t0_c0`, `t`.`active` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`publish_start` AS `t0_c2`,
>   `t`.`publish_start_local` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`create_time` AS `t0_c4`,
>   `t`.`last_modify` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`title` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`url` AS
>   `t0_c7`, `t`.`short_desc` AS `t0_c8`, `t`.`content` AS `t0_c9`,
>   `t`.`image` AS `t0_c10`, `t`.`comment` AS `t0_c11`, `t`.`hightlight`
>   AS `t0_c12`, `t`.`vote` AS `t0_c13`, `t`.`type` AS `t0_c14`,
>   `t`.`users_id` AS `t0_c15`, `t`.`newspaper_id` AS `t0_c16`, `t`.`del`
>   AS `t0_c17`, `t`.`region_id` AS `t0_c18`, `t`.`language_id` AS
>   `t0_c19`, `t`.`adult` AS `t0_c20`, `users`.`id` AS `t1_c0`,
>   `users`.`email` AS `t1_c1`, `users`.`password` AS `t1_c2`,
>   `users`.`author_name` AS `t1_c3`, `users`.`location` AS `t1_c4`,
>   `users`.`last_login` AS `t1_c5`, `users`.`active` AS `t1_c6`,
>   `users`.`remember_me` AS `t1_c7`, `users`.`rank` AS `t1_c8`,
>   `users`.`paypal_acc` AS `t1_c9`, `users`.`url` AS `t1_c10`,
>   `users`.`about_me` AS `t1_c11`, `users`.`image` AS `t1_c12`,
>   `users`.`facebook` AS `t1_c13`, `users`.`google` AS `t1_c14`,
>   `users`.`del` AS `t1_c15`, `users`.`admin_active` AS `t1_c16`,
>   `users`.`create_time` AS `t1_c17`, `users`.`first_name` AS `t1_c18`,
>   `users`.`last_name` AS `t1_c19`, `newspaper`.`id` AS `t4_c0`,
>   `newspaper`.`name` AS `t4_c1`, `newspaper`.`create_time` AS `t4_c2`,
>   `newspaper`.`type` AS `t4_c3`, `newspaper`.`active` AS `t4_c4`,
>   `newspaper`.`url` AS `t4_c5`, `newspaper`.`location` AS `t4_c6`,
>   `newspaper`.`newspaper_category_id` AS `t4_c7` FROM `articles` `t`
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` `users` ON (`t`.`users_id`=`users`.`id`) LEFT
>   OUTER JOIN `newspaper` `newspaper` ON
>   (`t`.`newspaper_id`=`newspaper`.`id`) WHERE (t.del = 0 AND t.active =
>   1 AND articles_has_tag.tag_id = 42) ORDER BY t.publish_start DESC
>   LIMIT 10

Here is articles_has_tag table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles_has_tag` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `articles_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_articles_has_tag_tag1_idx` (`tag_id`),
  KEY `fk_articles_has_tag_articles1_idx` (`articles_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=93 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why  you did not use findAll? You put everything in condition. 
And second thing to mention in your SQL you don`t have relation articlesHasTags.

You can try this.

```
$blog = Articles::model()
   ->with("articlesHasTags" => array(
       'alias' => 'articlesHasTags',
       'together' => true, //join in single query
       'condition' => "articlesHasTags.tag_id = {$tag->id}"//may be use param?
   ))->findAll(array(
       "condition"=>"t.del = 0 AND t.active = 1",
       'order'=>"t.publish_start DESC",
       "limit"=>10,
   ));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated :** 
Try this.

```
$blog = Articles::model()->with(array('articlesHasTags' => array(
         'alias'=>'articleHTag', 'condition' => "articleHTag.tag_id = ".$tag->id)))->findAllByAttributes(array(),array(
        "condition"=>"t.del = 0 AND t.active = 1",
        'order'=>"t.publish_start DESC",
        "limit"=>10,
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you the answer. I changed it, but error message come again. I edited my question. Do you need more code?

Comment: Ty again. Error message is: "Unknown column 'articleHTag.tag_id'"

Comment: Update with articles_has_tag table.

Comment: Ty the help. There is the answer.